# Thesisdown won't knit PDF: Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown, but when trying to knit I'm getting the following message:

```
Quitting from lines 2-64 (thesis.Rmd) 
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> paste -> readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/mmazor/Documents/projects/inProgress/unequalVarianceDiscrim/Chudi/thesisdownUCL/prelims/00-abstract.Rmd': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to manually set the working directory?

Comment: Are you knitting `thesis.Rmd` or `index.Rmd`?  I've never used this package, but the [documentation](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown#indexrmd) would suggest the file you knit must be titled `index.Rmd`.  My apologies if you already knew this.  Let me know if this works and if so I'll un-delete my answer.

Comment: R can't find 'C:/Users/mmazor/Documents/projects/inProgress/unequalVarianceDiscrim/Chudi/thesisdownUCL/prelims/00-abstract.Rmd'. Are you able to access the file from anywhere else? I assume you are referring to your abstract.Rmd file from within thesis.Rmd.

Comment: Sorry yes I know this is very package specific, its just that I couldn't find where to report bugs or problems on their GitHub page.

Comment: @Pietro: yes I'm in the project directory

Comment: @JoshuaMire: neither works :(

Comment: @9314197: This file definitely exists, and I can open it

Comment: btw,in the console I'm getting 
Error: The specified directory 'C:/Users/.../index' does not exist.
although 
dir.exists('C:/Users/.../index') returns TRUE (and the folder does indeed exsit).

Comment: what happens if you run `markdown::render("C:/Users/mmazor/Documents/projects/inProgress/unequalVarianceDiscrim/Chudi/thesisdownUCL/prelims/00-abstract.Rmd")`? Do you still get a file not found error?

Comment: I'm getting 'the file does not exist'.

Comment: I get this error as well sometimes. Add a line in which you import the file in the environment and make sure to explicit all the working directory.

Comment: thanks @Pietro! what do you mean by importing the file to the environment and by making the working directory explicit?

Comment: cannot open file 'C:/Users/mmazor/Documents/projects/inProgress/unequalVarianceDiscrim/Chudi/thesisdownUCL/prelims/00-abstract.Rmd': No such file or directory

Based on this, it looks like the directory is wrong or the name of the file is misspelled